# What do you call a school with elementary, secondary and college department?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to know what do you call a school that has elementary, high school and college department? I once read a manga, one character said the -term- but I forgot what the -term- is, so... I searched the internet but the answers given were about three different types of education and so on,.. I see some magnet and charter school but I think it's not what I'm looking for. If it helps the manga I was reading was about a Japanese school.

Answer (score 1):

The term I’ve found is [K-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%E2%80%9316):

> K–16 is a movement in the United States to bring together the various levels of education for younger students, namely between the K–12 and the post-secondary education systems, and create aligned policy and practice in examination practices, graduation requirements, admissions policies and other areas.

For example:  [Why we need a K-16 education system](https://hechingerreport.org/we-need-a-k-16-education-system/).